# Create copy/instance of complete CI project and database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently working on a CI application and my requirement is -

1. Admin (not super admin) will complete a registration form, and a new CI directory with original-name_other-name will be created with a copy of a database too.
2. CI folder and database will have different names from original.
3. Need to modify configuration files in new CI directory.
4. Only few tables in the new database will remain same.

Appreciating your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful for others - 
Done by using this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#104020

I am able to copy complete directory with this and also can change database settings by writing config files:)